# The SVG image is not showing in chrome

Tags: html, svg

I worked on this project a couple of months ago and it worked fine. I open it up today and the SVG images are not showing on chrome. It does show in other browsers though. This is how I’m using them.

```
 <svg>
     <use xlink:href=“img/sprite.svg#icon-user”></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your SVG has no `width` or `height` or `viewBox` declared?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Although you could shorten `<use>` with self closing tag:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href=“img/sprite.svg#icon-user”/>
</svg>
```

Could it be that your image was moved/deleted/renamed and other browsers are just caching it?

Answer (score 0):

You state it's visible in one browser but not another, so that indicates that the image is where it should be.  Is there any possibility of any CSS affecting "icon-user"?

Which browser works and which doesn't?  Having more detail may help lead to an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and it was caused by symbol `id` duplicated in `sprite.svg`

It was reproducible only when chrome loading svg file from disk cache.
*More details in [related PR](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform-admin-ui/pull/1444#issuecomment-669829764)*

Make sure you don't have any duplicate ids, even if it's not an `icon-user`.